# What does record drugs mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> ***RECORD DRUGS** HAUL AT AIRPORT*

The text above was extracted from book *Practical English Usage by Michael Swan page 292*.

Please, I'd like to know what does *RECORD DRUGS* mean?  Could anyone explain me what's that?

Are *drugs*, and *record drugs* different? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a slight error in parsing the sentence, which is where the confusion comes in: **record modifies haul here, not drugs**.

That is, the headline is not referring to a 'haul of record drugs', but to a 'record haul of drugs'.

'Record haul' then means 'haul that set a new record', and in context that can be assumed to be a record for largest size.

Answer (score 1):

**Record drugs** is an abbreviated version of **a record amount of drugs** that was shortened to be a headline.

In this case, **record** is like the record time in a sporting event. It means more drugs were found than had ever been found before.